# Python: Open several Websites with webdriver in different Breakpoints

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, screenshot, breakpoints

I´m really new to programming with Python.

I want to write a code that opens a URL in different Breakpoints (1280px / 768px / 320px) and then take screenshots from the site.

So far this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import time

# Set Breakpoint for different View
Breakpoints = [1280, 768, 320]

"""
Open invisible Website in Breakpoint 1280
"""
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1280, 800))
display.start()
"""
Open the Headless Chrome Webdriver
"""
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get('https://example.com')
driver.maximize_window()

"""
Take Screenshots and Save as File
"""
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('Screenshot_BrPt_1280.png')
time.sleep(1o)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('Screenshot_BrPt_768.png')
time.sleep(1o)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('Screenshot_BrPt_320.png')
```

My question is now: 
How can i rewrite this code that he loops through the different Breakpoints, open the site in the different Breakpoints an take a screenshot of every breakpoint?

Comment: use the python for loop

Comment: thanks, i was too stupid to write the right for loop :/ Now i tried a little bit an it works .. Thanks a Lot !!